# Setting Wix H1 element text equal to JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, html, velo

new to Wix and JavaScript here. I want to set a H1 element to a JavaScript variable. I have encountered the problem that Wix doesn't allow direct access to DOM, as stated in different Stack Overflow questions. I am specifically trying to do `document.getElementById` but that isn't allowed, instead I have to use Wix's own namespace. I am encountering the problem on this line: `$w("#text").text = chosenwebsite;`. Here is my full code:

```
// Velo API Reference: https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/api-overview/introduction
/* global document */

$w.onReady(function () {

    function getRandomInt(max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
    }

    const websites = ["Internet Archive", "number 2 ", "number 3"];
    const chosenwebsite = websites[(getRandomInt(3))];
    $w("#text").text = chosenwebsite;
    console.log(chosenwebsite);

});
```

And here is the code on the H1 element: `<h1 id="text">websites</h1>` (that's it, nothing else). And yes, I have set the element id to "text" within the actual Wix editor. This is the error message I keep getting: "Property 'text' does not exist on type 'HtmlComponent'". I have tried swapping out "text" for "html" but that didn't help

Thank you.

Comment: The Wix HtmlComponent [is not an HTML or jQuery element](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/$w/htmlcomponent). It's its own thing with an _extremely_ limited API.